# Formatar número para apenas 2 digitos

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho um script que retorna: 4.499999999999999

Mas eu queria que ele retornasse apenas 4.4 ou arredondasse para 4.5, so nao quero que fique mais de 1 digito após a virgula, como fazer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para arredondar para o número mais próximo, o mais simples é usar `toFixed`:

```js
var x = 4.499999999999999;
var y = x.toFixed(1);

document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<p>" + y + "</p>";
```

Já para arredondar para baixo, é necessário o uso da função `floor` e mais algum cálculo:

```js
var x = 4.499999999999999;
var y = Math.floor(10*x)/10;

document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<p>" + y + "</p>";
```

Note que o primeiro método converte o número para uma string, enquanto o segundo apenas realiza um cálculo com ele (o resultado continua sendo um número). Não consigo pensar num exemplo, mas é possível que mesmo após o cálculo o número não seja tão exato quanto você pretende (dadas as limitações da representação em ponto flutuante) - de modo que é aconselhável utilizar `toFixed` *também* no resultado, caso você use o método 2.

Answer (score 5):

**Se o numero está em formato *string* e queres arredondar para *string* tens duas possibilidades:**

1 - manter em string e cortar simplesmente o tamanho depois do ponto (floor)

```
var n = '4.499999999999999'.split('.') ;
n = [n[0], n[1][0]].join('.');                          // '4.4'
```

2 - arredondar sendo 4.5 no caso do seu exemplo

```
var n = parseFloat('4.499999999999999', 10).toFixed(1); // '4.5'
```

**Se o numero for em formato *number* e queres arredondar para *number* tens três possibilidades:**

1 - round (arredondar para a casa mais próxima)

```
var n = Math.round(4.499999999999999 * 100) / 100;      // 4.5
```

2 - ceil (arredondar para cima)

```
Math.ceil(4.499999999999999 * 10) / 10;                 // 4.5
```

3 - floor (arredondar para baixo)

```
var n = Math.floor(4.499999999999999 * 10) / 10;        // 4.4
```

Comment: +1 e ainda é possível usar **ambas** as estratégias, se aplicável (ex.: converter de string pra número, arredondar usando o método de escolha, e converter de número pra string de novo).